# Storing Data With Same Primary Key Dynamodb

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to store data in a way such as:

Their are 100 different types of fruits each fruit has a primary key of type "Fruit" so that when I query for "Fruit" all of the fruits are returned.

However, Dynamodb requires primary keys to be Unique.

So I am wondering how I would design my database scheme in order to achieve these results or is there another solution I should use in AWS?

Comment: Since it doesn't have any scenario of unstructured data it is better if you can try the AWS RDS rather than going into DynamoDB. It will reduce the unwanted complexity here.

Comment: RDS is an option but if you want to use DynamoDB then you have to learn how to structure your data for it. Specifically, you need to plan for how your data will be queried in the DB design, this is unlike a relational design. The docs are excellent and you should start there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html Edit to add: if you want more than one item with the same partition key then you need a sort key (but the docs explain this).

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey

There are two types of primary keys:

- Partition key – A simple primary key, composed of one attribute known as the partition key.
- Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a composite primary key, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.

It is not possible to store the same primary key in the format of a single partition key in one DynamoDB table.

To achieve what you are looking for, you will need to create a composite primary key on this table.

Let's create a new table **OganicProduct**, and then we create a composite primary key on this table. The attribute names for the primary keys are **type** and **subType**. Now you would need to put the value of **type** to be 'fruit' and value of **subType** to be their fruit type respectively.

(Note that the combination of type and subType should be able to uniquely identify an item in this table.)

So now to list all the fruits you can simply perform a query to get the results:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name OganicProduct \
    --key-condition-expression "type = :type" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":type":{"S":"fruit"}}'
```

To get a single fruit with a particular fruit type, what you can do is specifying a sort key in the key condition expression. Now the query would look like:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name OganicProduct \
    --key-condition-expression "type = :type and subType=:fruitType" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":type":{"S":"fruit"}, ":fruitType":{"S":"apple"}}'
```

Note that you could also store vegetables in the same table, as the attribute names of the primary keys are generic. To store vegetable records you simply put the value of **type** to be **vegetable**.

Query for listing all vegetables:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name OganicProduct \
    --key-condition-expression "type = :type" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":type":{"S":"vegetable"}}'
```

Query for fetching single vegetable for a given type

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name OganicProduct \
    --key-condition-expression "type = :type and subType=:vegeType" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":type":{"S":"vegetable"}, ":vegeType":{"S":"broccoli"}}'
```